# Varadic and template template parameters and partial specification for tree node class

Tags: c++

As the new standard gains popular, programmers are able to use `template template parameter` along with `varadic template` to define a class template that looks like:

```
/* C++ code */
template <template <class...> class container = std::unordered_multimap, typename... args>
class basic_node {
    public:
    container<args...> set;
};

/* class partial specialization */
template <typename key, typename value, typename hash, typename pred, typename alloc>
class basic_node<std::unordered_multimap, key, value, hash, pred, alloc> {
    protected:
    std::unordered_multimap<key, value, hash, pred, alloc> set;
};
```

My idea is to define a class template that contains a set of its child in the composed container member:

```
/* We use CRTP to avoid complain about incomplete type tree_node */
class tree_node : public basic_node<
        std::unordered_multimap, 
        std::string, /* key: name tag in text */
        tree_node, /* CRTP on value : element object in container */
        std::hash<tree_node>, /* some compatible hash */
        std::equal_to<tree_node>, /* some compatible equal_to */
        std::allocator<tree_node>> /* some a default allocator */
{
    public:
    /* ERROR: tree_node is of incomplete type because the compiler is now on it */
    //std::unordered_multimap<std::string, tree_node, std::hash<tree_node>, std::equal_to<tree_node>, std::allocator<tree_node>> set; /* inherited members */
};
```

Is this approach sound? I mean, I used to confuse about the curiously_recurring_template_pattern (CRTP) idiom `template tree_node<std::unordered_multimap<tree_node<std::unordered_multimap<tree_node<std::unordered_multimap<...>>>>>>...` induced by design but now it seems handy to me if the above works, or maybe?

EDIT:

1. Rectified parameters for std::unordered_multimap.
2. Thanks and CRTP it is by the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is about the *"recursion"* with `struct S : C<S /*, ..*/>`, it is fine.

it is the idiom [Curiously_recurring_template_pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).